# UITableViewCell Animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I am stuck with a tableview where cell are displayed in stack format.Any suggestion from expertise how to implement this kind of tableview.

(i.e i need to display the one cell behind another cell. On Tapping any cell, the cell should animate and shows complete contents of cell)

[image]

EDITED:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     int defaultCellHeight = 30;

     if(isSelected)
        defaultCellHeight = 60;

    return defaultCellHeight; 
}
```

Comment: why is the problem u r facing

Comment: displaying the one cell behind another cell.

Comment: Show us your `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` in your viewController?

Answer (score 1):

You can create this type of TableView by giving shadow of UITableViewCell. 
Here i give you to Some links that might be helpful in your case.

https://github.com/mystcolor/jtgesturebasedtableviewdemo
https://github.com/OliverLetterer/UIExpandableTableView
https://github.com/binho/TicketSaldo

[Follow This is best the Site for all Controller Ever.](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=UITableView)

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/bobmccune/Core-Animation-Demos If you look for core animation,then hope this demo works for you.